# How to get taxonomy list of custom post type by post id via REST API in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have an issue with custom post types taxonomies.

I can't get taxonomy by the custom post id, instead I'm getting all taxonomies list, even if custom post hasn't any taxonomy.

I tried: `/wp-json/wp/v2/portfolio_tag?portfolio=2842`

It works for posts, but not for custom post types.

How can I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Those taxonomies are exposed for the REST API?

```
'show_in_rest'  => true,
'rest_base'     => 'tax-api',
'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller'
```

Comment: Yes, my taxonomies are exposed for REST API. For example, I can get custom post information by taxonomy id: /wp-json/wp/v2/portfolio?portfolio_tag=291, but can't get it in reverse order.